# How to vertically align text in a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have problems vertically aligning text in my table.

I define new column type like this:

```
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
```

And this works for all column but last one. Any idea why doesn't it work for the last one?

The second question: how to vertically align text in multi-column rows?

Here is the whole example of my code.

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,superscriptaddress,unsortedaddress,twocolumn,showpacs]{revtex4}

\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}



\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htp]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Summary.} {\small\label{table:S2}}\centering 
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|M|M| }


\multicolumn{3}{M}{LONG TEXT}\\[4ex]\hline
      &  text         &   text \\\hline
text  &  complex text & complex text \\[6ex]\hline
text  &  complex text &  complex text   \\[6ex]\hline
text  & complex text  & complex text  \\[6ex]\hline

\multicolumn{3}{M}{LONG TEXT}  \\[4ex]\hline
     & text            &  text  \\\hline
text &  complex text   & complex text \\[6ex]\hline
text & complex text    & complex text   \\[6ex]\hline
text &   complex text  & complex text \\[6ex]\hline


  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: I don't succeed in compiling your example: `! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (D): \`c' used. ...... l.33   \end{tabularx}`

Comment: `D` is an unknown (to me) column type

Comment: I suspect that the `\\[6ex]` screws up the vertical spacings for vertical centering of that `M` columns

Comment: sorry, D was there by mistake. I changed it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can simplify your code using `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,superscriptaddress,unsortedaddress,twocolumn,showpacs]{revtex4}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htp]
    \caption{Summary.}\label{table:S2}
    \begin{tblr}{
        width=\linewidth,
        colspec={X[2]X[c]X[c]},
        hline{2-Z}={solid},
        vline{1-Z}={2-5, 7-Z}{solid},
        row{1,6}={ht=4ex},
        row{3-5,8-Z}={ht=6ex},
        row{2,7}={abovesep=1ex},
        row{1,6}={abovesep=2ex},
        }
        \SetCell[c=3]{c} LONG TEXT & & \\     
        & text & text \\
        text & complex text & complex text \\
        text & complex text & complex text \\
        text & complex text & complex text \\
        \SetCell[c=3]{c} LONG TEXT & & \\
        & text & text \\
        text & complex text & complex text \\
        text & complex text & complex text \\
        text & complex text & complex text 
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I cant compile your MWE. Error: Missing \begin{document}. I guess that is caused by used document class (is it obsolete as far as I know)`.

Comment: @Zarko I compiled it with an updated version of TeX Live 2022, with no errors.

Comment: I test with recent version of MiKTEX. I also try with Overleaf, but it still use TeX Live 2021, which use "ancient" tabularray package. Your proposition work fine with `article`! +1 1 for nice answer!

Comment: @Zarko With Overleaf, with TeX Live 2021, you can't use `Z` in `hline`, `vline`, and `row` options. If you substitute it with a number, it works also with Overleaf. I think it is a new feature of `tabularray`. Thank you for the +1.